# How to call and pass values to rest method with @QueryParam through angular

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am new to rest and I need to call and pass values from angular controller to rest @QueryParam method.

This is my rest code which i need to call and pass values:

```
@GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<DictionaryDetails> getAvailableDictionaries(@QueryParam("name") String name,
            @QueryParam("domain") String domain, @QueryParam("businessDomain") String businessDomain, @QueryParam("type") String type) throws ApplicationException {
        try {
            return availableDictionaries.getAvailableDictionaries(name, domain, businessDomain, type);
        }
```

This is my controller:

```
$scope.addRule = function(isValid) {
        if(isValid) {
//I have to pass the values which i am getting in $scope.ruleModel to rest method
            RulesService.addRule($scope.ruleModel);
}
}
```

Can anyone please help me out in doing this, i have searched on net too, but didn't get any working solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking how to make REST call from Angular application ?

Comment: The service above will accept a request in the the format :  http://hostname:port/?name=xxx&domain=yyy&businessDomain=zzzz&type=xyz

Comment: yes, actually i know how to call rest from service through path param but i don't know how to do so with @QueryParam. So any help regarding this will be valuable

Comment: `url?name=thename&domain=thedomain&type=thetype`

Comment: Here is a simple example to call REST service from angular. https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/.

Comment: Hints how to add params  in the above example :  $http.get('http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting?name=' + $scope.name + '&type=' + $scope.type )

Comment: Thank you ManMay and peeskillet